# What's a good tutorial for developing professional MVC applications with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am hoping this doesn't get flagged as subjective since everyone's idea of "good" can be different.  However, I know that you know what I mean, so, instead of flagging this question, feel free to edit the subject if you think it could be presented in a more objective manner.  This is also not a duplicate of [a good tutorial for .Net development with MVC, spring.net and NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913450/a-good-tutorial-for-net-development-with-mvc-spring-net-and-nhibernate).

I come from WebForms and need to learn MVC.  I came upon [this tutorial on MSDN](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started) which has been great for understanding the basics of the MVC design pattern.  However, it's just enough to teach someone the bare minimum so that they have everything they need to know to build a rudimentary ASP.NET MVC application.  From what I've seen, the methods illustrated there aren't exactly what I'd put in a professional, enterprise solution which is exactly what I am about to start working on.  I'd like to jump straight from the basics to advanced development, so I am interested in a tutorial/guide that has achieved popularity for being a solid resource for MVC development and best practices.

I realize that this question could have multiple answers, only one of which can be selected.  However, there's still the upvote system, so answerers can still get points and the upvotes will still serve as indicators for helpful answers which is really what SE is all about.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good starting point, it would be to check the [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net) site. it's certainly a good place to start. There would you find many tutorials for your purpose.

Furthermore, if you are about to buy a book, check PRO ASP.NET MVC 4 by Adam Freeman, [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-Adam-Freeman/dp/1430242361/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1387461608&sr=8-1&keywords=Pro+ASP.NET+MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361).
It's really a masterpiece.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've looked at it, but NerdDinner helped me out when I was getting started -

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

http://nerddinner.com/

Answer (score 0):

`I'd like to jump straight from the basics to advanced development, so I am interested in a tutorial/guide that has achieved popularity for being a solid resource for MVC development and best practices.`

In my opinion, using a framework in enterprise level requires deep knowledge of every part of it. why a component/class is designed, what is the purpose of it, how do we use it, what's the best practice, etc.

In this way I have found the [Programming Microsoft ASP.NET MVC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735662843) by Dino Esposito very helpful. The book's aim is to explain the mechanics of the framework and effective ways to use it.